# Why is my solution incorrect? AM GM inequality

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The problem is: Let $p+2q=3$ and find the maximum of $pq$.
Of course I could solve this as below:
$$pq=(3-2q)q=-2(q-\frac{3}{4})^2+\frac{9}{8}$$
so, the maximum is $\frac{9}{8}$.

However, I got another solution i.e. using AMGM inequality.
$$\sqrt{pq} \leq \frac{p+q}{2}$$
This gave me the answer $\text{max} (pq)=1$ and I think this is wrong. But I have no idea what is wrong in AMGM solution.

**AMGM solution**
$\sqrt{pq} = \frac{p+q}{2}$ iff $p=q$. so let $p=q$ and then $p=q=1$. This means $pq\leq 1^2=1$, so the maximum of $pq$ is $1$.

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you get max (pq)=1.

Comment: Hello Salahamam, I edited my post and added it.

Comment: AMGM says $pq$ reaches its maximum $\frac{p+q}{2}$ when $p=q$. By $p+2q=3$ I got $p=q=1$ so I thought $p=q=1$ would give the maximum i.e. $1$.

Comment: Is my answer what you want.

Comment: In the AMGM solution, why did you assume that $\sqrt{pq}=\frac{p+q}{2}$? The AMGM inequality does not imply that $pq$ reaches a maximum when $p=q$. This can be easily seen by realizing that the product $pq$ increases if $p$ is increased and $q$ is kept constant (assuming that $q$ is positive).

Answer (score 5):

AM-GM tells you that $\sqrt{pq}\leq\frac{p+q}{2}$ with equality iff $p=q$.  In particular, this implies that **if $p+q$ is held constant**, then $pq$ is maximized when $p=q$, since $\sqrt{pq}$ must always be at most half of the constant value of $p+q$.

But in your problem, $p+q$ is not constant.  So you know that $\sqrt{pq}\leq\frac{p+q}{2}$ is always true, but you can't say $p+q=2$ to conclude that $pq\leq 1$.  For instance, if $p=2$ and $q=1/2$, then $p+q=5/2$, and so all AM-GM tells you is that $\sqrt{pq}<\frac{5}{4}$ so $pq< \frac{25}{16}$.

Comment: You're genius, this is exactly what I wanted to know! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

it is about your second solution : we know $\sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}$ so use it correctly.

we suppose $p+2q=3$ then take $x=p , y=2q$
$$\color{red}{\sqrt{(p)(2q)} \leq \frac{(p)+(2q)}{2}}$$ this mean 
$$\sqrt{2pq)} \leq \frac{3}{2}$$ to the power of two 
$$2pq\leq \dfrac94 \to 
pq \leq \dfrac98 \to \max{(pq)}=\dfrac98$$

Comment: Thank you. But I knew your solution and my question is  why my second solution is incorrect.

Comment: @ciatina :I show the correct using of inequality , all you did is incorrect use of $\large {\sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}}$

Answer (score 2):

We have for $a,b \ge 0$,

$$\sqrt {ab}\le \frac {a+b}{2}$$

if $a=b $ then $\sqrt {ab}=\frac {a+b}{2} $

but if $a\ne b $ then
$$\sqrt {ab} <\frac {a+b}{2} $$

the max of $\sqrt {ab }$ could not be $\frac {a+b}{2} $, it depends on the condition satisfied by $a $ and $b $.

For example, suppose that the condition is
$$p+2q=4$$
then the max is attained for $p=2$ and $q=1$.
$$\sqrt {pq}=\sqrt {2}\approx 1.
414 $$
$$\frac {p+q}{2}=\frac {3}{2}=1.5$$

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, for every given pair of $(p,q)$, $\displaystyle\sqrt{pq}\le\frac{p+q}2$ holds. But the existance of a pair $(p_0,q_0)$ such that the equaity holds does not imply that it gives the maximum $pq$ for all pairs of $(p,q)$. There might be some pair $(p',q')$ such that $\displaystyle\sqrt{p'q'}\neq\frac{p'+q'}2$ but $p'q'>p_0q_0$.